# TypeError: distance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self2'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
class Point:
    """Two-Dimensional Point(x, y)"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        # Initialize the Point instance
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        # """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

The class has a function called magnitude. I want to create a function which can tell the magnitude distance between two points. The following is an expected output:

```
point1 = Point(2, 3)
point2 = Point(5, 7)
print(point1.magnitude)
    3.605551275463989
print(point1.distance(point2))
    5.0
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
  @classmethod
    def distance(self, self1, self2):
        pointmag1 = self1.magnitude
        pointmag2 = self2.magnitude
        bsmag =  pointmag1 - pointmag2
        bsmag2 = pointmag2 - pointmag1
        if pointmag2 > pointmag1:
            return combsmag2
        else:
            return combmag
```

This code always gives me the TypeError: distance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self2'. Any way to fix this?

Comment: distance requires two arguments self1 and self2 as per your definition `def distance(self, self1, self2):`. Therefore when calling it here `print(point1.distance(point2))` will give the error because only one argument is provided.

Comment: `self1` and `self2` are _very_ confusing choices for variable names and makes your code harder to understand than it needs to be.

Comment: That is not how you compute the distance between two points

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. If you'd like to explicitly pass both `Point` instances to your `distance` function, define it outside the `Point` class:

```
def distance(point1, point2):
    pointmag1 = point1.magnitude
    pointmag2 = point2.magnitude
    ...
```

and call it with:

```
point1 = Point(2, 3)
point2 = Point(5, 7)
distance(point1, point2)
```

If you'd like to keep the interface you wrote in your example though - `point1.distance(point2)` - then you need `distance` to be an instance method, not a class method:

```
class Point:

    # all your other code still here

    def distance(self, other):
        pointmag1 = self.magnitude
        pointmag2 = other.magnitude
        ...
```

In this case `self` *is* point1, and now `other` is `point2`.

(Note your `distance` method won't work as is, the variables `combsmag` and `combsmag2` are never defined, but that's unrelated to the error you're asking about.)

Comment: Don't forget that the formula is completely hosed as well